# Cannot access USB drive - non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown

Tags: command-line, partitioning, usb, mount, usb-drive

I am trying to access my FAT32 USB drive.  There is an error when I try accessing it.  I just want to access it read-only.

The error I get is:

```
Error mounting /dev/sde at /media/mink/34D2-84FB:
Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sde" "/media/mink/34D2-84FB"'
exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'
```

What commands should I use to access this drive?

Answer (score 1):

ExFAT is *not* the same thing as FAT32; exFAT is an extended version of FAT, as described on [its Wikipedia page.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exfat) It requires a new driver. If the disk is FAT32, you should use the filesystem type `vfat` (or `msdos` if you want to limit yourself to 8.3 filenames). If the disk uses exFAT, then you need a driver for same, which is not standard. (I believe one is available via the Filesystems in Userspace (FUSE) subsystem, but I've never used it.)